# Assembly 80x86 Loop should not loop for ever?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, x86-16

I have the following code:

```
assume cs: code, ds:data
code segment
start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds, ax

    xor cx,cx
    repeta:
        inc cx
        xor cx,0
        loop repeta

    mov ax, 4Ch
    int 21h

code ends  
end start
```

By my knowledge it should loop for ever or until error, but actually it does not. Why?

How I imagine that it works:

```
xor cx,cx - cx = 0
```

enters: `repeta` code segment

```
 inc cx  - cx = 1
```

does nothing

```
xor cx,0 - cx is still 1
```

Verify if `cx` is different from 0, if true jump to label `repeta`

```
loop repeta
```

In reality it does not repeat, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop will end after the first iteration, because the `loop` instruction will decrease `cx` to zero, then check if it is non-zero.

Ref: http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/loop.html

> "Decrements CX by 1 and transfers control to label if CX is not Zero."

Answer (score 1):

According [to this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Loop_Instructions), the `loop` instruction decreases `ECX` and jumps unless `ECX` is zero.

And if `ECX` is `1` before the `loop` instruction, then the `loop` instruction will decrement it to zero and *not* jump.